# How to group by with a rule with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Microsoft Office is not my favourite platform, but at the moment I have a problem, that I need to solve in MS Access.

I have a table `example` that, for example, contains:

```
|not_unique_id|qty|val
|    1        | 1 | 10 
|    2        | 1 | 5 
|    2        | 10| 10  
|    3        | 1 | 3 
|    3        | 10| 2
```

From this table I need to extract unique_id with lowest `qty` and representing `val`:

```
|unique_id|qty|val
|    1    | 1 | 10 
|    2    | 1 | 5 
|    3    | 1 | 3
```

At the moment I have:

```
SELECT not_unique_id as unique_id,MIN(qty),MIN(val) FROM example GROUP BY not_unique_id
```

that will yield incorrect results for the third entry. How can I get the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT     e.not_unique_id AS unique_id,
           e.qty,
           e.val
FROM
(SELECT    not_unique_id,
           MIN(qty) AS MinOfqty
 FROM      example
 GROUP BY  not_unique_id) q
INNER JOIN example e
ON         q.not_unique_id = e.not_unique_id AND
           q.MinOfqty = e.qty
ORDER BY   e.not_unique_id;
```